# Deletion on the ajax callback issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dashboard in my website which contain some entries in table, each entry in the table have a `delete` button. When user click over the `delete` button a Ajax call happens and I am deleting that entry in the callback function. My code :

```
$(".del").live({
    click: function () {
        $.post("/Home/DeleteTemplate", {
            name: $(this).parent().siblings("td:first").children("a").html()
        }, function (data) {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove(); //Inside the callback
        });
    }
});
```

Now my problem is that if I was deleting the row in the callback function the row was not removed from the entries immediately. I have to close and open the dashboard again to see the result.

But if I delete the entry outside of the callback function then it removed at the same time:

```
$(".del").live({
    click: function () {
        $.post("/Home/DeleteTemplate", {
            name: $(this).parent().siblings("td:first").children("a").html()
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").remove(); //Outside the callback   
    }
});
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` does not refer to your selector inside callback, do this:

```
$(".del").live({ click: function () { 
  var that = $(this); // added this

  $.post("/Home/DeleteTemplate", 
        { name: that.parent().siblings("td:first").children("a").html() }, 
        function (data) { 
        that.parents("tr").remove(); // used "that" here
        }); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: change `$(this)` to `that` in data also

Comment: Thanks @Sarfraz it works , but just for curiosity i want to know that if `this` is not refer to my selector in the callback then how the entry was deleted when i reopen the dashboard?

Comment: @KingKong: I am talkiong about `$(this)` inside the callback or ajax handler itself not outside it :)

Comment: yes i am also talking about inside of callback, ok i think i was not clear, lets try it one more time. I want to know how my first code ( which i send with my question ) delete the entries if `$(this)` is not refer to the selector ?

Comment: @KingKong: Well it shoudn't as per the rules of `this` keyword in JavaScript, I can't say anything but you might want to ask a new question with a DEMO if you can which would help analyze it. To know more about `this` keyword in JavaScript, see: http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/ but also notice that jQuery `manipulates` it as per its needs which might also be the case here.